# Using a mapped type in a tuple

Tags: typescript

How would I type this in TypeScript:

```
function arrayToObject(array, mapper) {
    const result = {};
    for(const item of array) {
        const [key, value] = mapper(item);
        result[key] = value;
    }
    return result;
}

// returns { '1': 2, '2': 4, '3': 6 }
arrayToObject([1,2,3], v => [v, v * 2])
```

Specifically, I want to have TypeScript make sure that the tuple result from mapper is a valid key and value. This doesn't work:

```
function arrayToObject<TItem, TObject>(
    array: TItem[],
    mapper: (t: TItem) => [P in keyof TObject, TObject[P]]
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming TS3.4 and using [`const` assertions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#const-assertions), (the technique can be altered to support TS3.3 and not require such assertions, but it's tedious), the strongest typing I can come up with is:

```
function arrayToObject<A, K extends keyof any, V>
  (array: readonly A[], mapper: (x: A) => readonly [K, V]): { [P in K]: V } {
  const result = {} as { [P in K]: V };
  for (const item of array) {
    const [key, value] = mapper(item);
    result[key] = value;
  }
  return result;
}

const obj1 = arrayToObject([1, 2, 3] as const, v => [v, v * 2] as const)
// const obj1: {1: number, 2: number, 3: number}

const obj2 = arrayToObject(["a", "b", "c"] as const, k => [k, 0] as const);
// const obj2: {a: 0, b: 0, c: 0}
```

That will at least preserve any literal key values the compiler knows about in the return type of the mapper.  The type system doesn't have much support for [higher rank types](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/115/higher-rank-and-higher-kinded-types) outside of some specific [generic function improvements](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions) so it's hard for me to think of any way for the compiler to understand that, say,

```
const obj3 = arrayToObject(["a","b","c"] as const, k => [k, k] as const)
```

will end up as type `{a: "a", b: "b", c: "c"}` instead of the still-correct-but-not-very-specific type `{a: "a"|"b"|"c", b: "a"|"b"|"c", c: "a"|"b"|"c"}`.  Oh well.

Hope that helps; good luck!